# Event Handling in Julia

Tags: asynchronous, events, event-handling, julia

Does the Julia Language have Event Management/Handling Functionality, and if yes, how would you implement it in your program(syntax)?

Note: I am aware of packages `DiscreteEvents.jl` and am Inquire about built in functionality that comes with the language and not through third party packages.

Comment: what do you mean by an "event" in your question?

Comment: "In programming and software design, an event is an action or occurrence recognized by software, often originating asynchronously from the external environment, that may be handled by the software. Computer events can be generated or triggered by the system, by the user, or in other ways."

Comment: There was something about events in the documentation, but that allowed you to wait for an event to be fired (through `notify(event)`) rather than attach a callback function and move one.

Comment: Why refuse third party packages?  Even languages like JavaScript that are used primarily within an event framework use third pary packages, such as node.js, and they are not part of the language as such.

Comment: Here is threading docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/   (look at Base.Threads.Condition) and here is documentation on couritenes https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/   The problem is that you have not specified on what type of event you are looking for. Such question is to general for SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rather should be closed.